# problem with try catch (catch doesnt run)

Tags: android, try-catch

I have a piece of code that loads a URL HTML and save it as a string.
I used a `try` and `catch` because the app crashes when the user doesn't have an internet connection.

But the app still crashes and codes that are in `catch` doesn't run but `try` part is ok.

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.Search_View);
        searchView.setIconified(false);
        searchView.clearFocus();

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                Log.i("html", "TextSubmitting");
                try{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),query,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.i("html", "Try");
                Ion.with(getApplicationContext()).load("http://www.google.com").asString().setCallback(new FutureCallback<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Exception e, String result) {

                        Log.i("html", result);
                    }
                });

                }
                catch (Exception ex){Log.e("html", "Catch");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); ex.printStackTrace(); }
                return false;
            }

        });
```

I wonder anybody could help me!

Comment: Can you show error log when app crashes? please.

Comment: Nothing just this warning: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41618c50)

Comment: If there's an exception then there will be a proper error log, not only this message. You should add that as well to your question to make it easier to help you

Comment: Yeah, my question is here, I don't know why the catch doesn't run! It's weird. It's like I don't even put a try catch there :(

Comment: Does the app crashes when there's an internet connection ?

Comment: in `onCompleted` check if the `Exception` is null and then show the results.

Answer (score 0):

try to  catch `IOException`

```
 catch (IOException ex) {
     Log.e("html", "Catch");
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
     ex.printStackTrace(); 
     return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but I got an error: IOException is never thrown in the corresponding try block. I don't know where the problem is!